# What value should be given to a Tcl dict for minimum memory?

Tags: memory, dictionary, tcl

I need a dictionary, "just for the keys", that is, the values are of lesser importance.
Which value will consume the least amount of memory? "0" "", something else?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I've missed something. What am I saying? Of course I've missed something as I can't think of a reason to do it this way rather than just putting the "keys" into a list and using list operations. What have I missed? (Upvote to @DonalFellows for his excellent answer to the original question.)

Comment: This list that you are talking about is to be searched for existance vs. a different sourced database. Number of elements is > 1e6

Comment: OK, so rather than search the list with [lsearch] you make a dictionary where each list element is a key and the value is irrelevant, and use [dict exists]? I've never done that myself, is it much quicker?

Comment: nurdlaw, in very large lists, yes. for 1e6, it is roughly 20x faster. Because searching and creating the the dict dict will be O(n), whereas a list will be, at best, O(nlog(n)), and if you do not sort it, O(n^2), which means 1e6 faster.

Answer (score 6):

Tcl shares constants under the covers, so you can use pretty much anything as long as it is a literal. But the empty string is almost certainly going to be a pre-defined constant in your script anyway (even if you don't notice it) and is pretty short. Or go with a single-character alphanumeric string, which will generate a shorter string form of dictionary (and have practically no difference otherwise). A `0` is a single-character alphanumeric string, of course.

In my own code, I would mostly use something like `"dummy value"` for the value. The cost is only a few bytes *total* more most of the time, and yet it's much clearer to me that it doesn't mean anything, so if I come back to the code later I don't try to figure out what I was doing with the value…

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I believe better expressed as one rather than a continuation of the dicussion in comments...

I follow the argument in the comments above about the comparative efficiency of list and dict key searching, I thought I would do some tests and present the results.

I constructed a dictionary with a million keys, an array with a million entries and a list with the dictionary keys via:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 1000000} {incr i} {
    set idx [expr rand()]
    incr arr($idx)
    dict incr dic $idx
}
set rands [dict keys $dic]
```

Incidentally, this took about 5.88 seconds excluding the final `set rands...`.

I then timed searching for different random numbers in the list with `lsearch`, the dictionary keys with `dict exists` and the array with `info exists arr()` with the following results for 1000 iterations:

```
lsearch $rands [expr rand()]      26349.115 microseconds per iteration
dict exists $dic [expr rand ()]      14.357 microseconds per iteration
info exists arr([expr rand()])       14.652 microseconds per iteration
```

Interesting. Not surprising, but I do like to see some numbers.

I then reread the OP's last comment, noticed the reference to sorting, tried sorting the list and using `lsearch -sorted`. Sorting the list took about a second.

```
lsearch -sorted $sortedRands [expr rand ()]   19.304 microseconds per iteration
```

it's reassuring that `lsearch` works pretty well with a sorted list, when you tell it that the list is sorted.

However, if I leave out the `-sorted` option, it takes **much** longer

```
lsearch $sortedRands [expr rand()]     120206.369 microseconds per iteration
                                       123604.209 microseconds per iteration
```

I was so surprised by this that I did it twice. I also repeated the `info exists arr(...` and found the same results as earlier, so it isn't simply that my machine has got much slower.

Doeas anyone have any ideas why the normal search of a sorted list is so slow?

Comment: This is basic CS. When a list is sorted, then the search engine can use bi-section, or a derivative of it. If you stumbled upon a value which is smaller, you can look up, or down.
 If the list is not sorted, then the engine has to look through all the values, which is slower.

Comment: I fear I'm still missing something - searching the original list is much slower than searching the dictionary with `[dict exists]`. `[dict exists]` takes about as long as `[info exists]`. Fine, the dictionary keys, and all the known variable names are stored in a structure that allows for fast searching.

Comment: Sorting the list and using `[lsearch -sorted]` is also quick; fine, you can use clever search algorithms to take advantage of the fact that the list is known to be sorted. I don't understand why searching a sorted list, without using clever algorithms, takes five times as long as searching an unsorted list without using clever algorithms.

Comment: It is a rule of the thumb. It actually be "at most", not 5.
If you search for values that are in the middle, then you use just 1 iteration. The hash function is (average) C1*O(1) = c1.
Whereas for sorted, it is C2*O(log(n))=c2*6. See that if c1 > c2, the difference may be very small. The search is through a sorted list may take about 5, not through an unsorted. If I have written through unsorted, then it is wrong.